# Why I cannot search arcore with LG G6(LGM-G600L) in google play yet?

Tags: android, google-play, android-8.0-oreo, arcore

I want to use arcore samples in LG G6(LGM-G600L).
It was reported the phone is supported arcore in arcore homepage, but I cannot use it yet!
(https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices)
Of Course, I had upgrade android 8.0.
Do you know why I cannot use arcore yet?

Answer (score 1):

According to their documentation on ArCore 1.2, you can simply download ArCore1.2.apk and directly install on your cellphone, if you are unable to install from playstore.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The document in arcore site was not updated before. Then the document is updated now. And I can use it in G6 now.